# How to stop a functional component being rerenderd react

Tags: reactjs

I have a functional component that is being rerenderd, and because it has a css animation in it, the animation starts from the beginning causing weird visual issues.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it in React.memo() wrapper. As long as it does not receive new props during a re-render, it's not going to re-render.

```
// You use the wrapper like this:
const ScrollAction = React.memo((props) => {
// Your ScrollAction Component
})
```

Comment: I actually exported the scrollaction wrapped with memo and that worked for me :)

Comment: Mark the answer as correct if this helped you, to help next visitors to focus on the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I exported the scrollaction wrapped with memo and that worked for me :)

```
export default memo(ScrollAction);
```